# "Import 'filename' could not be resolved" error when attempting to import Class from another file in Google Colab using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, import, google-colaboratory

[image]

When attempting to import a Class from another file in Google Colab I receive the error "Import 'filename' could not be resolved (reportMissingImports)" when hovering the cursor over `preprocess` on the line reading `from preprocess import TextPreprocessor`.

At the beginning of the second code block I have tried:

```
from google.colab import drive
import sys
path_to_module = '/content'
```

`from preprocess import TextPreprocessor` line equivalent seems to work for other people online in different IDE's. Am I missing any further imports or possible Google Colab settings in regards to the file path?

My imports are

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```

Comment: The error present in the screenshot is not the same as the one you mentioned, right? Can you provide a correct screenshot then, please?

Comment: @thmslmr Screenshot updated

Comment: have you tried using `%cd` instead of `cd` in the previous cell?

Comment: @thmslmr same result

Comment: I’m not sure to understand. If you run the cell as it is on the screenshot you got the resulting error ? Then the import is working.